# C# Ignore Character

Tags: c#, escaping, delimiter

I creating a nunit test case:

```
[TestCase("O'Hare")]
```

but it always shows up as

```
[TestCase("O\'Hare")]
```

in the Test Explorer. How do I get rid of the `\`?

Comment: You don't have to escape the `'` character in a C# string. I'm guessing that's your problem.

Comment: Have you tried double apostrophe?  As in ''.  I don't mean quote "

Comment: The \ is the escaping of the `'` character. Why does that bother you?

Comment: it is correct... you actual text is **O'Hare**

Comment: @Ian that results in [TestCase("O\'\'Hare")]

Comment: @CharlieKilian I'm not trying to escape the '. a slash appears before it, I need to remove that.

Comment: Did you tried using `@` the verbatim literal?

Comment: Oh dear, I guess you're stuck with it then!  Why does it matter?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Ohhhhhh I thought it would be an issue, thanks. Make that an answer and I'll select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\` is the escaping of the `'` character being elwhich is escaped by the debugger. It doesn't actually alter your code.